# Kubernetes resources definition

Tags: kubernetes

Reading [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/#resource-types) a resource is like cpu and other requirements from pods.

I then don't understand why the [documentation](https://kubernetes-v1-4.github.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_create/) then says, that you can create resources with `kubectl create -f`. Is that not creating pods - and pods is not a resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second link, the term `resource` refers to kubernetes API objects, such as Pods, Deployments or Services. You can create those objects/resources using `kubectl create -f`.

It doesn't mean cluster resources as in CPU, memory, etc. Those resources are the resources that Pods use from the cluster.